# I would like only one application to run

Tags: cpu

I have some Mining software called MinerGate and I would like it to use as much CPU as possible. So I would like to completely close out of all programs, apps, etc... that aren't required to run Ubuntu, to speed it up. How could I do this? I want as much possible to stop running. Also MinerGate is a GUI so can't cut that out.

Comment: You could always try to install the LXDE Desktop as it is one of the lightest weight desktops there is but still have a GUI.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LXDE

Comment: I don't really want to reinstall Ubuntu, but what are some major differences between the two? (regular Ubuntu and LXDE)

Comment: That isn't reinstalling at all.  It is installing along side of what you already have.  You are probably looking at the Unity Desktop which is what Ubuntu comes with by default, unless you download a different flavor of it.  There are other desktop environments like GNOME, Xfce4, LXDE, etc.

Comment: So like dual-booting it? I don't really want a tri-boot(I have Kali Linux too).

Comment: Nope, not like dual booting.  It is a different Desktop Environment that is different than an actual OS.  When you boot to Ubuntu, you normally just type in your password and log in.  After you follow the instructions in the link I posted, it tells you how to select the LXDE instead of Unity.

Comment: You can run it on lower `nice` value.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it seems like MinerGate does have a command line interface:
https://es.minergate.com/faq/how-minergate-console

This way you won't even need a Desktop Environment. To avoid automatically starting the graphical interface, disable lightdm, it may vary from an Ubuntu version to another, but for 16.04 (and higher) `sudo systemctl disable lightdm.service` should do it.

If you are not satisfied, use `ps -u $(whoami)` to list your processes and use `kill` on any unnecessary process. Still not satisfied? `ps -e` will list all processes, just be extra cautious when killing processes owned by root. Daemons may need to be killed with `systemctl`.

Add in Shreyash S Sarnayak's suggestion to set a low `nice` value and you will get the most out of it.